# Aggregare function in ON clause in JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why doesn't Postgres allow me using aggregate function in JOIN?

```
SELECT p.id, p.actual_price,
   h1.min_price, h1.max_price 
FROM (
  SELECT min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price, product_id
  FROM prices_history 
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY product_id
  ) AS h1,
  products p
JOIN (
  SELECT max(timestamp), price, product_id
  FROM prices_history 
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY product_id, price
  ) AS h2
  ON  h2.product_id = p.id 
     AND h2.price = h1.min_price
 WHERE 
  p.id = h1.product_id
 GROUP BY p.id, p.actual_price, h1.min_price, h2.max_price
 ORDER BY p.id;
```

ERROR:  column "min_price" does not exist
LINE 19:          AND price = min_price
                              ^
HINT:  There is a column named "min_price" in table "h1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: Please prepend ALL your columns with their table alias. I can't really tell where `min_price` is coming from.

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit join syntax... Switch to explicit `JOIN`  everywhere! (Because explicit JOIN chains are evaluated before comma separated joins. I.e. min_price isn't available in your ON clause.)

Comment: *"HINT: There is a column named "min_price" in table "h1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query."* `h1.min_price` ?

Comment: The problem is not that it is an aggregated value, but it is in a different branch of the `FROM` clause. A `JOIN` sees only the one table from the `FROM` list it is attached to...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, in an explicit JOIN chain, the ON clause can include references to _all_ prior tables (from left to right.)

Comment: You did not aliased 'max(timestamp),` in `h2`. Although it's not directly related for your question - you can omit it in your code.

Comment: Simply read my above comment and switch to explicit `JOIN`, voila!

Comment: @jarlh See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN A `JOIN` is in the form `T1 join_type T2 [join_condition]`, and the `JOIN` only sees this 2 tables. Additional `JOIN`s have the resulting "joined-table" of  the previous `JOIN` as `T1`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, more or less what I said.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah, and "more or less what i said", too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code below, I have marked the problem with proper explaination.

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.actual_price, 
       min_price, 
       max_price 
FROM   (SELECT Min(price) AS min_price, 
               Max(price) AS max_price, 
               product_id 
        FROM   prices_history 
        WHERE  timestamp > '2019-01-01' 
        GROUP  BY product_id) AS h1, 
       products p ,
       join (SELECT Max(timestamp), 
                    price, 
                    product_id 
             FROM   prices_history 
             WHERE  timestamp > '2019-01-01' 
             GROUP  BY product_id, 
                       price) AS h2 
         ON p.id = h2.product_id 
            AND price = min_price  -- <= This join is same level with subquery h1.
                                   -- you cannot use min_price here
WHERE  p.id = h1.product_id 
GROUP  BY p.id, 
          min_price, 
          max_price, 
          p.actual_price 
ORDER  BY p.id;
```

For fixing this, I also replaced legacy comma seperated join with proper inner join

```
with h1 as 
(
    SELECT Min(price) AS min_price, 
           Max(price) AS max_price, 
           product_id 
    FROM   prices_history 
    WHERE  timestamp > '2019-01-01' 
    GROUP  BY product_id

), h2 as 
(
    SELECT Max(timestamp), 
            price, 
            product_id 
     FROM   prices_history 
     WHERE  timestamp > '2019-01-01' 
     GROUP  BY product_id, 
               price

)
SELECT p.id, 
       p.actual_price, 
       min_price, 
       max_price 
FROM  h1, 
inner join products p  
  on p.id = h1.product_id 
    join  h2 
      ON p.id = h2.product_id 
         AND price = min_price   
GROUP  BY p.id, 
          min_price, 
          max_price, 
          p.actual_price 
ORDER  BY p.id;
```

Comment: and dont use legacy comma seperated joins.

Comment: I see. So it cannot be done this way because if I change the order in FROM, the WHERE clause breaks?

Comment: Thank you very much. Just have to remove comma in 'FROM  h1, inner join products p'

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answers, of course you can use your original query using Derived Tables, just change the *implicit* to an *explicit* join:

```
SELECT p.id, p.actual_price,
   h1.min_price, h1.max_price 
FROM (
  SELECT min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price, product_id
  FROM prices_history 
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY product_id
  ) AS h1
JOIN
  products p
ON p.id = h1.product_id
JOIN (
  SELECT max(timestamp), price, product_id
  FROM prices_history 
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY product_id, price
  ) AS h2
  ON  h2.product_id = p.id 
     AND h2.price = h1.min_price
 GROUP BY p.id, p.actual_price, h1.min_price, h2.max_price
 ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment!

Answer (score 0):

You are using "table expressions". A table expression (such as `h2`) cannot reference a previous one (such as `h1`), or its columns, except in the `JOIN` clause.

If you want to `h2` to use `h1`, then use **Common Table Expressions** (CTEs for short). Your query could be rephrased as:

```
with
h1 as (
  SELECT min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price, product_id
  FROM prices_history 
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY product_id
),
h2 as (
  SELECT max(timestamp), price, product_id
  FROM prices_history 
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY product_id, price
  )
SELECT p.id,
  p.actual_price,
  h1.min_price, h1.max_price 
from products p
join h2 ON p.id = h2.product_id
join h1 on h2.price = h1.min_price
       and p.id = h1.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, h1.min_price, h1.max_price, p.actual_price
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: A column returned from a prior table expression in the same explicit JOIN chain can be referenced in the ON clause. OP's problem is caused by the implicit, comma separated join.

Comment: Although they are equivalent - it's the first I hear `subqueries`/`subselects` are called as `table expressions`. But it's just a terminology. @jarlh there is nothing `implicit` per se in join-condition in `WHERE`-section.

Comment: @AlexYu Subqueries/Subselects are called "table expressions" only when they are located in the `FROM` clause (or `JOIN` clause). Otherwise, they are just "subqueries". On other literature they are alse called "Inline views".

Comment: @AlexYu: Old-style comma-delimited joins where you join in the WHERE-clause are called *implicit join* while `JOIN ON` is an *explict join*. And a Standard SQL *Derived Table* (no matter how you name it: *table expression*, *inline view*, *subselect*) in FROM is exactly the same as a CTE, it's just a syntax variation (besides WITH RECURSIVE). And a Select in the WHERE-clause is called *subquery*.

Comment: @TheImpaler Although I prefer SQL-92: there is nothing implicit in SQL-89 **inner** joins. Implicitness starts only when you try **outer** joins in SQL-89 syntax. And even in SQL-92 syntax one is free to move predicates between `ON` and `WHERE` sections - result **must** be the same (for inner joins) no matter where it was written. If an RDBMS treat them different - it's a bug in this RDDBMS that must be corrected.

Comment: @AlexYu: The syntax error is correct, `products` and `h2` are joined first before joining the result to `h1`.